# Knockout JS blur event binding occurs 2 times

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, frontend

I have this simple input

```
<div class="input-group" data-bind="attr:{id: 'date-rec-datepicker-calendar-' + invoiceId()}, liveEditor: value">    
<input class="edit form-control" type="text" 
           data-bind="attr:{id: 'date-rec-editor-' + invoiceId()}, 
           value: value,
           hasFocus: value.editing, 
           event: { blur: value.stopEditing }" />
</div>
```

and this KO extender

```
this.value = ko.observable();
ko.extenders.liveEditor = function (target) {
            target.editing = ko.observable(false);
            target.edit = function () {
                target.editing(true);
            };
            target.stopEditing = function () {
                target.editing(false);
            };
            return target;
        };

ko.bindingHandlers.liveEditor = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable.extend({ liveEditor: this });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, function () { return { editing: observable.editing }; });
            }
        };
```

I have no clue why, after focusing the input, when I click outside the input, the blur event attached function is triggered two times, so the stopEditing function is hit 2 times. I saw this problem is very common with the blur event.

Comment: you should recreate your issue in a snippet so we can see what is going on, your code is incomplete and not possible to understand without the rest of the code. the knockout userbase is getting smaller every day as it is so unclear issues with insufficient input from the questioner are much rarer to be resolved as you can see for yourself.